# File extension for Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains:MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 192 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Monaural

Tags: file-format

I got a audio file without file extention. I want to add file extention in that file. I just know that its a audio file. So I tried to check its type using `file` command.

```
alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cr1:~/Downloads$ file AUD-20200501-WA0004. 
AUD-20200501-WA0004.: Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains:MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 192 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Monaural
```

By seeing this output I am not able to find suitable file extention. I guess it can be `mp3` file. Please tell what extention should I give to this file?

Answer (score 2):

`contains:MPEG ADTS, layer III` yes its probably MP3.

Double check with ffmpeg :

```
ffmpeg -i /the/audio/file
```

Wich gives much more accurate information about media files